# No MessageBodyWriter for application/xml

Tags: xml, list, resteasy

I'm using Resteasy and just want to return a list of strings from my resource. It works with JSON but for XML I have the error that `Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.ArrayList of media type: application/xml`.

What should I do? I have tried may options in the web but nothing worked.

```
@GET
@Path("")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Wrapped(element = "resources")
public Response getResources() {

  List<String> resources = ts.getAllResources();
  //GenericEntity<List<String>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<String>>(resources) {};

  return Response.ok().entity(new GenericEntity<List<String>>(resources) {}).build();
  //return Response.ok(resources).build();
  //return resources;
}
```

Extract from pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.resteasy.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-atom-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE:**
I've noticed that I also has the following error when deploying in Wildfly 10.

```
WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /D:/Dev/Servers/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/service.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-2.2.7.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
```

Comment: do you annotate your class with `@XmlRootElement`?

Comment: Which class? The one implementing the web service?

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't manage to get it working directly, I created a workaround which implies creating a class encapsulating the list:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "resources")
public static class ResourcesListSerializerHelper {
  @XmlElement(name = "resource")
  @JsonProperty(value = "resources")
  public List<String> resources = new ArrayList<String>();

  public ResourcesListSerializerHelper() {
  }

  public ResourcesListSerializerHelper(List<String> list) {
      resources.addAll(list);
  }
}

@GET
@Path("")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response getResources() {
  List<String> resources = ts.getAllResources();
  return Response.ok().entity(new ResourcesListSerializerHelper(resources)).build();
}
```